# Why is $[0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ not compact in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, rational-numbers

> Statement: $[a, b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is not compact. Thus the interior of all compact subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\emptyset$.

I am trying to understand the first sentence. I read that a closed subspace of a compact space is compact, so for example, consider the unit interval $[0, 1]$ which is a compact space. Take a closed subspace $[0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ of $[0, 1]$. This set is closed since it just consists of all the rational numbers in between $0$ and $1$, including $0$ and $1$. So it is a closed subspace of a compact space. But why isn't this compact?

Comment: A closed subset *of a compact space* is indeed compact. And $[a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is ia closed subset of the space $\mathbb{Q}$. **BUT** the space $\mathbb{Q}$ is not compact, so the theorem you read does not apply.

Comment: I would like to point out that your question title talks about one space being compact *in another*. There's no such thing. A space is compact or is not compact, and any "surrounding space" is irrelevant. (This is different from closedness for example, where you always ask about one space being closed *in another*.)

Comment: The interval $(a,b)$ viewed as an interval of reals contains an irrational point $\gamma$.  Now let $U_0$ be the rational points $\lt \gamma$ and for $n\ge 1$ let  $U_n$ be the rational points greater than $\gamma+1/n$. Open cover with no finite subcover.

Comment: It's not closed in $[0,1]$.

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is not a compact space.  And a good example of this would be that the interval $(\sqrt{2},\pi)$ in $\mathbb Q$ is *closed* in $\mathbb Q$ because it contains all its limit points.  ($\sqrt{2}, \pi$ and all irrationals in between do not exist in $\mathbb Q$ so they can not be considered limit points as the "do not exist").  So $(\sqrt{2},\pi)$ is closed and bounded but it isn't compact for the usual reasons.  ($\{(\sqrt{2}+\frac 1n,\pi-\frac 1n)|n\in\mathbb N\}$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Try finding a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ that does not have a convergent subsequence in $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$.

Answer (score 5):

You can cover it with infinite number of open sets such that no open set overlaps (open intervals with irrational endpoints). If $\bigcup U_j = X$, but $U_j\cap U_k = \emptyset$ if $k\ne j$ you can't reduce the sets to a finite covering.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Find a sequence of closed, non-empty sets $C_n\subseteq [0, 1]\cap \Bbb Q$ for $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $C_n \subseteq C_{n-1}$ and $\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty C_n = \emptyset$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. If $C_n \subseteq C_{n-1}$, then $C_n \cap C_{n-1} = C_n$. How can it be possible then that $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n = \emptyset$?

Comment: @morphic Because there are infinitely many of them, they get smaller and smaller. For instance, if you let $C_n = [\frac12 - \frac1{2n}, \frac12 + \frac1{2n}]\cap \Bbb Q$, then $\bigcap C_n = \frac12$. However, in some other cases, there is no such element left at the end. You just have to construct it carefully.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$

Comment: I don't see any relationship between density and compactness. Can you explain

Comment: compact set is closed in a Hausdorff Topological space and so in metric spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You said, "A closed subspace of a compact space is compact." and then you tried using $[0,1]$ as the compact space. But $[0,1]$ is compact as a subset of the reals, as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, it's what you are trying to understand. The countable covering of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ by point sets in $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ has no finite subcover in $\mathbb{Q}$ which covers the whole set, because none of the sets in the cover overlap.

Comment: Specifically, take the countable cover, $\cup {F_i}$ of singleton sets ${F_i}$ where $F_i$ is the ith entry in the Farey sequence on $[0,1]$. There are no overlapping sets in the cover, each is a point, and a unique point, and their union is $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{q}$. So there is no finite subcover.

Comment: Meant singletons $\{ F_i \} \subset \mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in your argumentation is that the set $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ is *not* closed in $[0,1]$. Rather, the closure of $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ in $[0,1]$ is the complete interval $[0,1]$.

As non-closed set in a Hausdorff space, it cannot be compact.

Note that $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ *is* closed in $\mathbb Q$, but then, $\mathbb Q$ is not a compact space, so again you don't get a closed subspace of a compact space.